withNextIntl and withPlaiceholder do not work together in NextJS
I am using the latest NextJS 14. And in next.config.mjs file as above, I wrapped my nextConfig in two plugins, but when I deployed them to Vercel, it simply cannot be built. I am relatively new to this situation, so I stop using plaiceholder so switched to Jimp to blur my image, which works smooth. Nevertheless, I would like to know what's the solution here, in case I ever want to work in this setup again.
import createNextIntlPlugin from "next-intl/plugin";
import withPlaiceholder from "@plaiceholder/next";

const withNextIntl = createNextIntlPlugin();

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        hostname: "firebasestorage.googleapis.com",
      },
      {
        protocol: "https",
        hostname: "cdn.sanity.io",
      },
    ],
  },
  env: {
    POSTGRES_PRISMA_URL: process.env.POSTGRES_PRISMA_URL,
    POSTGRES_URL_NON_POOLING: process.env.POSTGRES_URL_NON_POOLING,
  },
};


export default withPlaiceholder(withNextIntl(nextConfig));


I stop using plaiceholder so switched to Jimp to blur my image, and Redis to cache it, which works smooth.


better not to use image for code answers since this now doesnt get indexed for search results
